# DIV with BORDER Hover problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" style="width:200px; height: 200px; border: 10px solid #ccc"> 
  contents.. 
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.container').hover(function() {
    console.log('in');
},
function() {
    console.log('out');
});
```

It makes `console.log` when `hover` occurs both on `border` and `div`.

**Objectives:**

```
1> Want to make a `hover` event only for `div`, but not for `border`.
2> Fire another `hover` event on `border`, but not for `div`
```

Are the possible? if, then I want your cordial help..

Comment: border is part of the div. the better approach would be placing one div into another and 'simulate' border using padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pragmatic solution would be to:

```
<div class="container" style="width:200px; height: 200px; border: 10px solid #ccc">
   <div class="inner" style="height: 200px;">
       contents.. 
   </div>
</div>
```

and

```
$('.container .inner').hover(function() {
    console.log('in');
},
function() {
    console.log('out');
});
```

Cleanest option imo. a javascript solution would be more complex and simply not worth it.

Answer (score 3):

The border IS the div, at least in part.

There's no event for specifically hovering over a border that I know of.

What you can do is have a nested div (within another div) and have a 10px padding on the internal one. This will give you 2 divs to work with and apply hover events to as well as looking the way you require.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jssSA/

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">Some content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer,#inner{width:300px; height:300px;}
#outer{
    background-color:#000;
    padding:10px;
}

#inner{
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#outer').hover(function(){
          console.log("outer in")},
          function(){console.log("outer out")});

$('#inner').hover(function(){
         console.log("inner in")},
         function(){console.log("inner out")});
```